# Is assuming - verb choice

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, verbs

Is "assume" an appropriate verb to use in this sentence?

We all need to acknowledge the great importance science is **assuming** nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a perfectly appropriate and natural use of "assuming*.

See sense C2 in the [Cambridge definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/assuming):

> to take or begin to have responsibility or control, sometimes without the right to do so, or to begin to have a characteristic:
>
> - *The new president assumes office at midnight tonight.*
> - *The terrorists assumed control of the plane and forced it to land in the desert.*
>   > * *The issue has assumed considerable political proportions* (= has become a big political problem).